# checkbox onclick function not called in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onclick

I have the following checkbox in HTML:

```js
function updateSettings(id, bit) {
  alert('0');
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="alert('1');updateSettings(0, 1);alert('2');" />
```

In IE11 on click I get alerts 1, 2 but not 0: the function is not executed at all.

In Chrome everything works fine.

Comment: It works in my IE 11: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvJmOv

Comment: @connexo, not in mine

Comment: @user4749485 IE has defined a function `updateSettings` on the document object, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue, but it's strage. If you change the function name to lower case, then it works.

```js
function updatesettings(id, bit) {
  alert('0');
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="alert('1');updatesettings(0, 1);alert('2');" />
```

**DEMO**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXLgxJ

**UPDATE**: As Zimmi has explained **updateSettings** is an inbuilt method `document.updateSettings()` in IE and this will be triggered on `onclick` event instead of our method `window.updateSettings()`

Comment: Wow that's weird, we are forced to use lowercase only in onclick functions from now on?

Answer (score 3):

The function `updateSettings` is defined in IE on the `document` object. See this [documentaion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

When you put a call inline, as in this case in an `onclick`, it will look first in the element itself if the function is defined. Then it will search the `DOM` tree up to  `document` to see if the function is defined (some elements are searched and some not, unfortunately I didn't know the rule governing this until  @user4749485 wrote his comment below), and after, as a last resort in `window`. As it find it, it runs it.

As you defined your own updateSettings probably on the global object (`window`), it's not fired in IE, because the function defined on the `document` object is found first.

End of mystery bug :-)

**UPDATE :**

@user4749485 pointed to the link explaining this at the [w3 site](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#internal-raw-uncompiled-handler), the information is in item 1.10 - Lexical Environment Scope. To sum it up :

```
<element onclick="functionFoo();">bar</element>
```

implies following procedure :

```
Does element.functionFoo exist ?  YES ==> use this function.
ELSE
Does element belong(1) to a form and form.functionFoo exist ? YES ==> use this function.
ELSE
Does document.functionFoo exist ?  YES ==> use this function.
ELSE
Does window.functionFoo exist ?  YES ==> use this function.
ELSE
crash.
```

(1) = an element belongs to a form != an element is inside a form element. Roughly it must be a form element, like in the question an input element.

Comment: @user4749485 Thanks a lot for your link, I've updated this post accordingly. That's great, we now have the exact information.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not to use an inline onclick event and instead use jquery to define an event for the checkbox:

```
    function updateSettings(id, bit) {
        alert('0');
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         jQuery("#cbMyCheckbox").click(function(){
              alert('1');
              updateSettings(0, 1);
              alert('2');
         });
    });
```

and then in your html:

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="cbMyCheckbox" />
```

Comment: It's a bit inconvenient in my case: checkboxes are auto generated and to define event using jquery would be much more complex: it would be necessary to get function parameters from some checkbox properties...

Comment: That's what HTML5 `data-` attributes are for ;)

Comment: @Terry good to know, thx. But auto generation is still simpler in my case ;)